# Corresponding web api function to accept file

Tags: asp.net, file, asp.net-web-api, upload, retrofit2

I am trying to upload file using retrofit, send it to the server side and save that file in my uploads folder.

This is my retrofit API instance:

```
@Multipart
@POST("file/uploaddocument")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadFile(@Part MultipartBody.Part file );
```

UploadFile:

```
private void uploadFile(Uri fileUri) {
    // create upload service client
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    MyApiEndpointInterface apiService =
            retrofit.create(MyApiEndpointInterface.class);

    // https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java
    // use the FileUtils to get the actual file by uri
    File file = Utils.getFileForUri(fileUri);
    // create RequestBody instance from file
    RequestBody requestFile =
            RequestBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse(getContentResolver().getType(fileUri)),
                    file
            );

    // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
    MultipartBody.Part body =
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestFile);

    // finally, execute the request
    Call<ResponseBody> call = apiService.uploadFile(body);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call,
                               Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            UploadProgressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.v("Upload", "success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            UploadProgressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.e("Upload error:", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

And I'm calling this method on button click as :

```
uploadFile(myfileuri);
```

This is my Web API call(Is this correct ? If not how to accept the image from client side ?)

```
 <HttpPost>
    <Route("api/File/UploadDocument", Name:="UploadDocument")>
    Public Function Upload() As HttpResponseMessage
        Try
            Dim UploadedPath As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles")
            Dim httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request
            If httpRequest.Files.Count > 0 Then
                For Each file As String In httpRequest.Files

                    Dim postedFile = httpRequest.Files(file)
                    postedFile.SaveAs(UploadedPath + "/")
                Next
            Else

            End If
            Dim message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "True")
            Return message
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex)
        End Try
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I done it...Posting here so that some one else might be found it useful

```
<HttpPost, Route("api/UploadFile")>
    Public Function Post() As HttpResponseMessage
        Try
            Dim httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request
            If httpRequest.Files.Count < 1 Then
                Return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            End If

            For Each file As String In httpRequest.Files
                Dim postedFile = httpRequest.Files(file)
                Dim filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/" + postedFile.FileName)
                ' NOTE: To store in memory use postedFile.InputStream
                postedFile.SaveAs(filePath)
            Next
            Return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex)
        End Try
    End Function
```